# Wicked pdf Can't use Footer and Header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I am using OS ubuntu 14.04. then I using wicked pdf and wkhtmltopdf_binary version 0.12.5.4, I got error Failed to execute:
["/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "--encoding", "utf8", "--margin-top", "10", "--margin-bottom", "17", "--margin-left", "12", "--header-spacing", "12", "--header-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20221011-1427-voc4e8.html", "--footer-html", "file:////tmp/wicked_footer_pdf20221011-1427-labzfr.html", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20221011-1427-19qqjdg.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20221011-1427-10x5vk0.pdf"] Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: The switch --header-spacing, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --header-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.The switch --footer-html, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored

but if I am used use_xvfb: true on wicked_pdf.rb, no error but the footer and header is not generated.

do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `wkhtmltopdf`, You might need to track down or build a version of `wkhtmltopdf` for your platform.

Comment: thanks @ram, i have tried to upgrade wkhtmltopdf, but not found for ubuntu 14.04 arm64, 
do you have any suggestion?